# How to find two Objects intersected / not while using animation in xcode?

Tags: animation, uigesturerecognizer, collision-detection, intersection

I'm working on finding intersection point of two objects.I'm using basic animation code to move two Image1 one is form left --> right & Image2 form bottom --> top.this action will perform when you long press on the screen(anywhere).

Can any help me out how to find the both are intersected / not.I just want to display alert when both are intersected.

[image]
[image]

here is my code ..

```
-(IBAction)gesture_action:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self first];
        [self colide:gesture];
    } else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"middle");
    } else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"end”);
    }
}

-(BOOL)dragIsOverTrash:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint pointInTrash =[gesture locationInView:self.image1];
    return [self.image1 pointInside:pointInTrash withEvent:nil];
}


-(void)colide:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ([self dragIsOverTrash:gesture]){
        NSLog(@" hitted the cloud ");
    } else {
        NSLog(@" not hited ");
    }
}

-(void)first
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                     animations:^{
                        image2.frame=CGRectMake(106,5,108,128);
                     } 
                     completion:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                     animations:^{
                         image1.frame=CGRectMake(-250,25,240,128);
                     } 
                     completion:nil];
```

}

my Results :----

[image]

plz suggest if any other better ways...to solve this problem.
Thanks for your time guys ,i appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Please could you add actual code and not an image.

Comment: @Popeye here is the link of code http://pastie.org/8856832 ..sorry for dealy buddy.can you help me out ...

Comment: Please provide your code in the question and not as an image or on a link. Links can expire.

Comment: Sure @Popeye buddy .i will change it..do u have any idea to proceed my question !!!

Comment: In all honesty I haven't even looked at the code yet, this is why I wanted you to format correctly. I'm in work so that link you provided actually gets blocked for me and I hate screen shots of code, I just refuse to look at them.

Comment: @Popeye you can check now i pasted code..

Comment: Think you need to learn somethings, this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` I have removed this tag. Please make sure to format the code correctly and on your `completion:^(BOOL value){}` blocks you can just pass `complete:nil` if your not doing any completion block.

Comment: Actuvally i have some code there to perform another tasks ..not related to this ..any way i removed and updated now .check the code now once @Popeye.

Comment: It's very bad to give us incomplete code, if you've only given us half the code then we might not be able to solve for you. You need to provide all code for us to review and provide an answer based on that.

Comment: im just calling another method @Popeye .that is not related to this..that i even removed in my main code also,the code i pasted currently is the complete code only.so can you tell me the how i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

HI Guys After a long Work on with my buddy's help ,i Finally did it. here is the code which will solve this problem ..using timer .then you can easily find out the results.

```
   -(void)callthismethod

   {

    CALayer *layer = image1.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGRect NewObjectFrame =  layer.frame;
    CALayer *layer2 = image2.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGRect SprintFrame = layer2.frame;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(NewObjectFrame, SprintFrame)) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Colided");
    }
 }
```

Thank you my friend who helped me to solve this problem once again :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some change i got solution with diffrent way hope that helps you:-

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface animationViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *square4;
    UIImageView *square3;
}

@end
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    float frameWidth=320;
    float frameHeight=480;


    square4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(frameWidth/10, frameHeight/1.35, frameWidth*.1, frameWidth*.1)];
    square4.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"square.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview: square4];
    CGPoint origin4 = square4.center;
    CGPoint target4 = CGPointMake(square4.center.x+300, square3.center.y);
    CABasicAnimation *bounce4 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    bounce4.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin4.x];
    bounce4.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target4.x];
    bounce4.duration = 0.5;
    bounce4.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    bounce4.autoreverses = YES;
    [square4.layer addAnimation:bounce4 forKey:@"position"];




    square3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(frameWidth/10, frameHeight/1.35, frameWidth*.1, frameWidth*.1)];
    square3.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"square.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview: square3];
    CGPoint origin3 = square3.center;
    CGPoint target3 = CGPointMake(square3.center.x+300, square4.center.y);
    CABasicAnimation *bounce3 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    bounce3.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin3.x];
    bounce3.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target3.x+50];
    bounce3.duration = 1.3;
    bounce3.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    bounce3.autoreverses = YES;
    [square3.layer addAnimation:bounce3 forKey:@"position"];

    [super viewDidLoad];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                                     target: self
                                   selector: @selector(checkCollision:)
                                   userInfo: nil
                                    repeats: YES];


}


-(void) checkCollision: (NSTimer *) theTimer{


    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(((CALayer*)square3.layer.presentationLayer).frame,
                           ((CALayer*)square4.layer.presentationLayer).frame)) {
        //handle the collision
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"wow!"
                                                        message:@"detect Failed!"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"detect hit");

    }

}
```

it's OUTPUT like this:-

[image]

For testing i am using NStimer you can modify as par your requirement hope this helps you.